# Автоинкремент с N количеством нулей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Приветствую.
Можно ли в Таблице Базы данных силами одного только SQL сделать, авто-инкрементируемый  первичный ключ не просто  вида  `1`,`2`,`3` а такого `00001`,`00002`,`00003` и т.д. ?

Пробую создать таблицу с `zerofill` :

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `number_tasks_id` int(5) zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

на что `sql` выдает ошибку :

> 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: думаю, на тригерах сделать можно. Только видимо его придется делать строковым, а это для первичного ключа как бы не очень. Но скорее всего у Вас вся загвоздка в том, что Вы хотите не хранить в базе так, а отображать пользователю

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, Вам надо это поле сделать `PIMARY KEY`

Comment: А не проще использовать printf, format или toString("выражение")  языков высокого уровня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `mysql` реализован дополнительный [атрибут `zerofill`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

```
mysql> create table zai (i int(5) zerofill auto_increment primary key, val int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into zai (val) values (1),(2),(3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from zai;
+-------+------+
| i     | val  |
+-------+------+
| 00001 |    1 |
| 00002 |    2 |
| 00003 |    3 |
+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Впрочем, не рекомендую на него полагаться. У вас вопрос очевидно относится к вопросам вывода данных - вот при выводе форматировать и правильнее. Если очень хочется форматировать силами SQL - есть строковая функция [`lpad`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```
mysql> select val, lpad(val, 5, '0') from zai;
+------+-------------------+
| val  | lpad(val, 5, '0') |
+------+-------------------+
|    1 | 00001             |
|    2 | 00002             |
|    3 | 00003             |
+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что тогда мне придется и инсерт делать такого вида : `INSERT INTO tmpfoo() VALUES (3,'value')`. Иначе говоря - никакого автоинкремента не будет, я в ручную заношу 3, 4, 5 и т.д. А БД только добавляет к ним ноли. Что бы понять какую цифру ставить придется делать еще один запрос - узнать сколько уже строк в таблице.

Comment: Поясните. В чём проблема lpad'ом в запросе или на приложении форматировать значение автоинкрементного поля?

Comment: "узнать сколько уже строк в таблице" - не имеет отношение к автоинкременту. Читайте теорию реляционных баз данных.

Comment: @nick_n_a я знаю, поэтому и говорю что так нельзя

Comment: @Мелкий если я заношу строчку в таблицу с автоинкрементируемым столбцом ID, то мне не нужно писать значение этого самого ID. С ZEROFILL  так не работает.

Comment: Я понял вопрос, для mysql нужно писать `insert into table1 values ( null, 'value')` вместо null он *(mysql) сделает автоинкремент* сам автоматически. Для других субд свои приколы (с автоинкрементом). В даном примере первое поле должно быть с опцией автоинкремент.

Comment: @nick_n_a теперь понял. спасибо.

Comment: А вообще в 90% СУБД (и mysql тоже) при insert просто не нужно указывать автоинкрементное поле в списке перед values, и оно заполнится само после вставки. Правда прийдется указать поля.